# Generalizing: closed projection iff X compact

Tags: general-topology

I was wondering what generalizations to locally compact spaces do we have for the known result that a space $Y$ is compact if and only if the projection map $\pi:X\times Y \rightarrow X$ is closed, for each $X$.

I was thinking something like $Y$ is locally compact if and only if $\pi$ sends closed sets to locally closed sets, or something similar. Does anybody know any result/counterexample?

Comment: Why the downvote, if I may ask? I'm relatively new to the site, I don't know each rule... a comment about it is welcome to improve my questions.

Comment: Unfortunately downvoting can be a little aggressive and rarely gets commented on

Comment: But what is a "locally closed set"?

Comment: @FShrike $E$ is an open subset of its closure, or equivalently, for each point in $E$, there is a neighborhood $U$ of that point such that $E\cap U$ is closed in $U$.

Comment: Thank you C Squared :)

Comment: @FShrike I'll try to be more precise for the next questions, maybe that was the problem... Thank you